# Is this a correct to prove that there are no solutions for these trigonometric functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, proof-verification, proof-writing

This is part of a problem that I've been doing; it turns out the way I was doing it was wrong but I've still got a question about one method I used in trying to prove the problem. I ended up trying to find the solutions to:
$$ \cos{z}=0 \;\; \land \;\; \sin{z}=2-\sqrt{3}   $$
Now I wrote the solutions to cosine as:
$$  C=\{\pi k-\pi/2 ,\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}\}  $$
and the solutions to the sine function as: 
$$ S_1=\{ \sin^{-1}(2-\sqrt{3})+2\pi k, \forall k \in \mathbb{Z} \} \text{ and } S_2= \{ \pi-\sin^{-1}(2-\sqrt{3})+2\pi k, \forall k \in \mathbb{Z} \} $$
Thus the solutions that we are interested are the ones that lie both in $C$ and in $S_1\cup S_2$. Thus:
$$ \text{Solutions}= C\cap (S_1\cup S_2) $$
Now I then went on to say that if that's the case then it should be true that (for $C\cap S_1$):
$$ \pi k -\pi /2 = \sin^{-1}(2-\sqrt{3})+2\pi n \;\; k,n \in \mathbb{Z} $$
or for the other one ($C\cap S_2$):
$$ \pi k -\pi /2 = \pi-\sin^{-1}(2-\sqrt{3})+2\pi n \;\; k,n \in \mathbb{Z}  $$

---

Now this is where my question is, with the two above equations if we rearrange the first one to:
$$ 2k-4n-1=\frac{2\sin^{-1}(2-\sqrt{3})}{\pi} $$
does this imply that:
$$\frac{2\sin^{-1}(2+\sqrt{3})}{\pi}\in \mathbb{Z} $$
And thus if it's not (it isn't) does it prove that the sets do not intersect at all?

Answer (score 0):

If $\cos z=0$ then $\sin z=1$ or $-1$ therefore there is no solution

Comment: yeah I know there aren't any solutions. I'm just curious if they way I went about trying to show it was correct. Thanks